# Как вывести по N строк из каждой группы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть новостной сайт, новости разеделены по секциям. Как вывести в одном запросе по N записей каждой секции?
Читал [тут](http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select16.php)

Пробовал такой запрос:

```
SELECT a.* FROM content_content AS a
  LEFT JOIN content_content AS a2 
    ON a.news_section_id = a2.news_section_id AND a.pub_date <= a2.pub_date
GROUP BY a.title
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
ORDER BY a.news_section_id, a.pub_date DESC;
```

Но после 10 минут простоя Мускул теряет соединение. Я же ожидал чуть ли не мгновенного выполнения. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Там много написано, да и по-ненашему. Вопрос всплывает часто. В mysql можно перенумеровать записи в группах с помощью локальных переменных, а затем вывести те у кого номер меньше N. Возможно даже есть в FAQ'е. Я на такие вопросы отвечал не раз. Сейчас лень искать. Если нужно -- найдёте

Comment: @alexlz там есть и на русском) только запрос не работает

Comment: Ну из моих ответов http://hashcode.ru/questions/305658/mysql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81 Если есть вопросы -- задавайте. Обратите внимание на установку @i в 1 при смене gallery

Answer (score 3):

Следующий запрос вернёт по 10 строк из каждой секции:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT *,
    /*если в предыдущей строке секция была та же, нумеруем строки внутри секции*/
    /*иначе присваеваем счетчику 1 (т.е. начинаем нумерацию новой секции)*/
    IF(@last_session_id=news_section_id, @I:=@I+1, @I:=1)N,
    /*присваеваем ид секции в переменную*/
    @last_session_id := news_section_id
  FROM content_context,
    /*инициализируем локальные переменные*/
    (SELECT @last_session_id := null, @I := 0)T
  /*сортируем по секции, затем дате в обратном порядке*/
  ORDER BY news_section_id, pub_date DESC
)T
/*выводим по 10 строк из каждой секции*/
WHERE N <= 10
```